# Python: midi to audio stream

Tags: python, audio, midi

I need convert/synthesize MIDI data to audio stream PCM data. What would be an easy way to do so?

Comment: http://is.gd/igp4m -- I've seen so many questions about converting MIDI to audio I had to write this.  Please take the time to read it if you are considering writing some software system which needs to do that.

Comment: @Nik: Surely I know all that (and I would think most people do as it is just logical). What do you think would be a better word instead of "convert" here?

Comment: I'd use the word "synthesize". ;) Sorry, I didn't mean to sound condescending; it just seems that this question gets asked a lot by people who underestimate the difficulty of doing this task.

Comment: Possibly 'render'. Although the link above has gone dead.

Comment: @NikReiman i'd like to read what you wrote about "audio to midi" but the link (is.gd/igp4m) is dead. could you post a permalink?

Comment: @samboosalis yeah, I migrated domains some while back. New link is here: http://www.mergeconflict.net/2010/12/just-for-record-you-dont-convert.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Take your pick](http://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonInMusic) on what you want to do, there is a MIDI section on the page.

Comment: It seems that none of the MIDI libs which are listed there can do what I asked for. Or did I miss one?

Comment: I am not aware of a specific answer to your question, however do glance over the libraries in the link, maybe they do serve your purpose. If you are aware of an external command/ software that can do this for you, then `subprocess` can help.

Comment: @Albert: Almost all of the MIDI tools in "Playing & creating sound" can handle it.

Comment: @Ignacio: I don't quite see how they support that. Can you explain?

Comment: You don't see how "... can either be used to play audio itself, or you can call a function that returns chunks of audio data..." supports that? Really?

Comment: I think my problem was that I didn't realized that the thing I want is called "synthesizer".

Answer (score 2):

I decided to code my own (based on timidity and subprocess). The code can be seen here:
https://github.com/albertz/learn-midi/blob/master/decode.py

I downloaded a prebuild binary of Timidty for MacOSX here:
http://www.merenbach.com/software/ports/timidity

And I installed the Freepats package from here:
http://freepats.zenvoid.org/

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

[midi2audio](https://pypi.org/project/midi2audio/)

Project description:

"Easily synthesize MIDI to audio or just play it. It provides a Python and command-line interface to the FluidSynth synthesizer to make it easy to use and suitable for scripting and batch processing. In contrast, most MIDI processing software is GUI-based."

Answer (score 0):

Is using Jython an option ? 
I think the javax.sound.midi classes would handle this.