# Is it possible for JFugue to output to an audio cast?

Tags: jfugue

I want to run JFugue on an Amazon cloud instance to create a music stream from data on the cloud instance...and then listen to the music stream on my local laptop via some audio cast system.  Is there any way to get JFugue to output a music stream in a way thats compatible input to any audio casting system?

Thanks.

Comment: Remember that JFugue produces MIDI output, and MIDI is data, not audio. It takes a Synthesizer to convert MIDI to sound. A more general question might be, "Is there a way to take a MIDI stream and convert it to an audio stream (e.g., streaming WAV)"?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4354963/python-midi-to-audio-stream